# how do I make tableviewcell height to autogrow

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, ios-autolayout

I have a tableviewcell with two labels and the label's height will change depending on the content so tableviewcell height will automatically change.

now how can I make tableview cell height to autogrow ?

Please clarify me if the tableview cell height will autogrow if the label height changes ?

Comment: Please show the code you've written and we can help you see where you're going wrong. To encourage people to help you, you show that you've _tried_ to help yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To make it tableview cell autogrow you have to keep in mind of the following two things in mind,

- Right constraint(top, bottom, right & left) for the UI elements inside the tableview cell.
- Usage of `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` & `estimatedRowHeight` property as follows,

  ```
  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100 // A rough estimated height for your cell.
  tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  ```

Refer the following tutorial for better indepth explanation on how to implement it.
http://matteomanferdini.com/the-correct-way-to-display-lists-in-ios-and-what-many-developers-do-wrong/#autolayout

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1KJQs0frbM

Comment: you mean to say I have to use just constraints that what you mean right .. or else do I have to do anything extra ?

Comment: Yes, you have to add right(correct) constraint, and the properties which I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: i have added leading,trailing and top constraints but its not auto increasing

Comment: What about the bottom constraint ? all four side constraint are mandatory for achieving auto increase. Once refer the links shared, you will get a clear picture.